# Display an icon based on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have a defined set of seven different post types and would like to display an icon for each one in the search results list.

I've got the following code to display the post type but have no idea how to extend it into an if

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type($post) );
echo $post_type->label ; ?>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
   $post_type = get_post_type($post);
   switch ($post_type) {
       case "type1":
           echo "<img src='label1.png'/>";
           break;
       case "type2":
           echo "<img src='label2.png'/>";
           break;
   }
?>
```

Comment: You can also access the post type directly from the `$post` object: `$post->post_type`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with CSS. If you're using post_class() in the search results it will have the post-type available within each post's classes for styling each type differently.

Then you just apply a different background image as an icon for each post type class.